# Android ViewPager Filter Items / Do Not Show All Items

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I'm currently developping my first Android Application. Now I'm at the point where I really don't know how to handle the problem on my own. My Main Layout implements a **ViewPager**:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/image_swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="590dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp" />
```

The Main Layout also implements a toolbar which owns this **menu item**:

```
<item
      android:id="@+id/show_favorites"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      android:icon="@drawable/heart_red"
      android:title="@string/show_favorites" />
```

**What I basically want to do**, is: when the user clicks the menu item with id @show_favorites, the Adapter for the ViewPager should be filtered. Every item presented in the ViewPager has an ImageButton (favouriteButton). The button can be grey or red. The button state is stored as SharedPreferences, means: every item has its own key fav1 - fav10 (10 items) and this key has value 0 (grey) or value 1 (red). So when someone clicks the menu item, I only want to show items in the ViewPager which are marked as favorite (so in SharedPreferences it is stored 1). All items with a 0 have to be hidden.

My **Adapter Class** looks like you can see below:

```
public class SwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter  {

/*
    Define the image resources for our image fragment
 */
private int[] image_resources = {
        R.drawable.island_maldives,
        R.drawable.island_kreta,
        R.drawable.island_australia,
        R.drawable.island_kosamui,
        R.drawable.island_domrep,
        R.drawable.island_bahamas,
        R.drawable.island_mallorca,
        R.drawable.island_philippines,
        R.drawable.island_seychelles,
        R.drawable.island_borabora
};

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public SwipeAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

/*
    Count the images in image_resources array
  */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_resources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view == (LinearLayout) object);
}

/*
    Create the page for the given position
    Set image resources and text about current position
 */
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_image);
    TextView textView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) item_view.findViewById(R.id.favourite_button);

    imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);

    // set tag for details
    imageView.setTag(position);

    textView.setText("["+(position+1)+"/10]");

    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("favInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // get the unique key consisting of fav and the current item position
    String key = "fav" + (position+1);
    imageButton.setTag(position+1);

    String value = prefs.getString(key, "0");

    // check if value of favorite key is 0
    // set image resource dependent on what value is set
    if (value.equals("1")) {
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
    } else {
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
    }

    container.addView(item_view);

    return item_view;
}

/*
    Remove a page for the given position
 */
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
}
```

And my **Main Activity** is organized this way:

```
public class SuggestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
SwipeAdapter adapter;

private final AppCompatActivity activity = SuggestionActivity.this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_suggestion);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.image_swipe);
    adapter = new SwipeAdapter(this);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // set the toolbar for the suggestion page
    Toolbar sToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.suggestion_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(sToolbar);
};

/*
    Add options menu at view start
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.suggestion_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/*
    Declare what happens when user clicks an item of the options menu
    @go_home start the CategoryActivity
    @filter TO DO
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.go_home:
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(activity, CategoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            return true;
        case R.id.show_favorites:
            Intent favIntent = new Intent(activity, SuggestionActivity.class);

            //
            // HERE IS WHERE I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO
            //

            startActivity(favIntent);

            return true;
        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/*
    Method for click actions on the favorite button
    @heart grey heart symbolizes no favorite (flag 0)
    @heart_red red heart symbolizes marked as favorite (flag 1)
*/
public void onClickFav(View v) {
    ImageButton favouriteButton = (ImageButton) v;

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("favInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    // get the unique key by getting the tag of the image button
    String c = v.getTag().toString();
    String key = "fav"+c;

    // get value stored with that key, default: if no value exists take 0
    String value = prefs.getString(key, "0");

    // check if value of favorite key is 0,
    // set image resource dependent on what value is stored behind the key
    if (value.equals("0")) {
        favouriteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
    } else {
        favouriteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
    }

    // do some magic text dependent on what value is set
    if (value.equals("1")) {
        Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "No favourite anymore...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "Woah, new favourite!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    String isFav;

    // switch value to opposite
    if (value.equals("0")) {
        isFav = "1";
    } else {
        isFav = "0";
    }

    // store shared preferences
    editor.putString(key, isFav);
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

**In sum:** The ImageButton state of each item in the ViewPager is already stored as SharedPreferenecs in form of tags 0/1. After clicking the menu item with id @show_favorites, I only want to show the items with 1 as stored value.

How can I do this? **Thank you** for your advice!

Comment: I'm working on something very similar. I have an ArrayList that stores the favourites; it has to be an ArrayList so that you can add items to it. In the Favourites activity the ArrayList is converted to an Array which is then passed to the PagerAdapter.